Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on Dell Latitude 5491 not working with Dell WD22TB4 Docking Station
I install Ubuntu 24.04 on a Dell Latitude 5491. But my Dell Dock WD22TB4 is not working.
Charging and USB and Ethernet are working, but I don't get Display Output.
If I run windows 11 in the laptop, everything works fine.
Does anybody know something about this issue?
